# Converting pandas series to a list, is not working as input to Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, list, pandas, pymongo

I have some data stored in a panda DataFrame and I would like to query my MongoDB with a list constructed from a single series in the DataFrame. When I convert the series with `.tolist()`  or the function `list()` I apparently get a list, but when I input this list in a Pymongo query I get the error:

`bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: <the first value of the list>`

**Here is an example that reproduces the error:**

So first creating a Mongo database:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd

db = MongoClient().test
db.collection.insert_many([{'key_x':1},{'key_x':2},{'key_x':3}])
```

Then I query the database for the documents where `key_x` is in [1,3]:

```
x_list = [1,3]
for doc in db.collection.find({'key_x':{'$in': x_list}}):
    print doc
```

As expected no error and the two entries `{'key_x':2}` and `{'key_x':3}` are printed to the console.

Now I try first transforming the list to a Pandas series and converting back to a list.

```
ser = pd.Series([1,3])
x_list = ser.tolist()

print type(x_list) #Checking to see if it is indeed a list
> <type 'list'>

for doc in db.collection.find({'key_x':{'$in': x_list}}):
    print doc
```

Then this error message is printed:

```
>bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: 1
```

Thank you very much for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different behavior arises from the different type of list's *elements*:

```
# first example
type(x_list[0])
int
# second example
type(x_list[0])
numpy.int64
```

One way to fix it is to use `ser.values.tolist()` instead of `ser.tolist()`. Apparently, pandas `tolist()` behaves differently than numpy's.

Comment: Thanks...@tcaswell just beat you to it :-)

Comment: This answer is better for noting that `ser.values.tolist()` works.  @Duffau you should report this as a bug against pandas

Comment: @tcaswell Just checked the issue tracker and someone posted this issue 3 days ago: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10904 ... Should i leave a comment with the SO-link in the issue tracker?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that pandas is return a list of `np.int64` objects, not built-in `int` objects.

```
In [50]: ser = pd.Series([1,3])

In [51]: type(ser.tolist()[0])
Out[51]: numpy.int64
```

The following

```
ser = pd.Series([1,3])
x_list = [int(i) for i in ser.tolist()]

for doc in db.test.find({'key_x':{'$in': x_list}}):
    print(doc)
```

works as expected.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much... will be more vigilant in checking value types in the future.